# Why does taking stdin from a file differ from receiving it over a pipe?

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

Using bash I often want to get the headings of a large csv file and search the rest for a particular entry. I do this as follows.

```
$ (head -1; grep mike) < tmp.csv
name,age,favourite colour
mike,38,blue
```

But taking the input from cat, or any other command doesn't work - it seems grep never gets passed the remainder of the file.

```
$ cat tmp.csv | (head -1; grep mike)
name,age,favourite colour
```

Why is there different behaviour in these two cases?

Comment: `wc -l test.txt` -output-> 3   `(head -1>/dev/null; wc -l) < test.txt` -outupt-> 2. !

Comment: I have some theories, but I can't reproduce this with bash 3.2.48 (Darwin). Which version are you using?

Comment: This is GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on a rhel 5.6 machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between reading from a pipe and reading from a file is that you can `lseek` on a file, but not on a pipe.

The behavior here looks (as seen through `strace`) like it's coming from `head`, not bash.  `head` will read a buffer and find the appropriate number of lines, then `lseek` backwards to the point where the last-output line ended, leaving the file handle open at that place.  As above, this works if it's reading a file, but not if it's reading from a pipe.

I can't think of any case *other* than what you're doing where this behavior in `head` makes sense, but there it is.  Learn something new every day, I tell ya ...

Answer (score 3):

Very strange. You should not rely on this undocumented behaviour, use something like this instead:

```
sed -n '1p;/mike/p' tmp.csv
```

Comment: It's not an undocumented behaviour. Everything works as expected (see evil ottos answer). It's just a bad practice - to use `(command1; command2)` construction to read data from the common standard input because the second one depends on behaviour of the first one. So you're right too with your command.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this reliably with bash 3.2.48. Either both succeed or both fail. But the underlying reason for the failures is how large the file is.

`cat` reads one buffer (4k-64k depending on the system) and hands it down the pipe. `head` consumes the entire buffer and then exits. `grep` then has access to the file after the buffer size. On my system, I can use your pipe only to `grep` thing further than one buffer into the file (so I can `grep` things at the end of a long file, but not at the beginning after using `head`).

It is possible that later versions of bash optimize the `<` operator (but not `cat`) to allow your trick work, but I don't believe this is supported behavior.